# Development kit for learning USB device driver development

Tags: usb, driver, usb-device, hardware, development

I want to learn writing device drivers for USB devices (on linux kernel or microcontrollers, if that matters). Hence, I am looking for sample USB development kit.

e.g. when I wanted to learn I2C, I could find hundreds of I2C based sensors, LCDs, switches, etc. Now I am looking for similar simple beginner level USB devices that can be used to learn USB driver programming. It could be a small thumb-drive shaped circuit board with LEDs and buttons, that I can blink or receive button press events over the usb.

Can someone please point me to such device or kits, if they exist. I searched a lot but always ended up with wrong search results, probably I need more fine-tuned search keywords. I do not want to begin with a USB mouse or USB keyboard to learn USB driver programming. I would love it to be simple to begin with.

**EDIT**
I am just adding the examples here which I found, it may help someone in future. However, I am looking for kits intended for USB development that are developer friendly (with documentation). The devices below are not.

Consider this example : https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7353 (a USB based LED lamp). I am looking for such kind of devices.

Another example : here is another article which makes of similar device : http://matthias.vallentin.net/blog/2007/04/writing-a-linux-kernel-driver-for-an-unknown-usb-device/

Comment: I'm not sure how many "USB drivers" exist. Like most systems use chips similar to FTDI products and repackage their driver. Things like hard drives etc. Use generic drivers... I get what your asking, and maybe I'm off base, but there might by other devices that are more custom vs USB.

Comment: It looks like you found it yourself, https://www.delcomproducts.com/webpage.asp?id=24 with an article explaining Linux driver for it. What else do you need?

Comment: Thanks.... I would still wait for any more answers because $60 is too much for that piece. Cheaper alternatives are most welcome.

Comment: Such "shopping" questions are firmly and fundamentally prohibited by site rules.  In practical terms, find some *useful* device with only closed drivers to write an open driver for.  Or if you are building a custom physical device, choose a scheme that will be easy to support on the host side, perhaps one for which a standard class driver *already* exists.  Essentially any USB-capable MCU board could be used if you really insist on inventing a problem to solve.